# Checking for same values and update array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I am working with Nodejs and I am stuck on this given below problem and looking for best practices to do it.

I have an array set that would be like this:

```
[
  { id: 'something1', score: 180, rank: 1, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 1280 },
  { id: 'something2', score: 180, rank: 2, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 1073 },
  { id: 'something3', score: 161, rank: 3, avatar: 'avatar_2', prize: 902 },
  { id: 'something4', score: 161, rank: 4, avatar: 'avatar_7', prize: 758 },
  { id: 'something5', score: 161, rank: 5, avatar: 'avatar_8', prize: 535 },
  { id: 'something6', score: 161, rank: 6, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 318 },
  { id: 'something7', score: 143, rank: 7, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 267 },
  { id: 'something8', score: 143, rank: 8, avatar: 'avatar_4', prize: 224 },
  { id: 'something9', score: 140, rank: 9, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 210 }
]
```

and now I want to add all those prizes that have identical scores and then divide them
by total players having the same score and then updating the existing array with new prize values.

Here is the sample output that I am looking for:

```
[
  { id: 'something1', score: 180, rank: 1, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 1176 },
  { id: 'something2', score: 180, rank: 2, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 1176 },
  { id: 'something3', score: 161, rank: 3, avatar: 'avatar_2', prize: 628},
  { id: 'something4', score: 161, rank: 4, avatar: 'avatar_7', prize: 628},
  { id: 'something5', score: 161, rank: 5, avatar: 'avatar_8', prize: 628},
  { id: 'something6', score: 161, rank: 6, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 628},
  { id: 'something7', score: 143, rank: 7, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 245},
  { id: 'something8', score: 143, rank: 8, avatar: 'avatar_4', prize: 245},
  { id: 'something9', score: 140, rank: 9, avatar: 'avatar_3', prize: 210 }
]
```

So what would be the best way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what do you need. Use map or find ol filter through the array, and let change on the object(s) what do you want. Was this helped you?

Comment: please add your try. what goes wrong?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: do a reduce on original array and create an average : score mapping . then do a foreach on the orignal array and update the prize with the average value from the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a hash table of totals first (I've used a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement)), and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data and replace the `prize` value of each object with the total that matches the `total` value in the hash table for that score.

```js
const data=[{id:"something1",score:180,rank:1,avatar:"avatar_3",prize:1176},{id:"something2",score:180,rank:2,avatar:"avatar_3",prize:1176},{id:"something3",score:161,rank:3,avatar:"avatar_2",prize:628},{id:"something4",score:161,rank:4,avatar:"avatar_7",prize:628},{id:"something5",score:161,rank:5,avatar:"avatar_8",prize:628},{id:"something6",score:161,rank:6,avatar:"avatar_3",prize:628},{id:"something7",score:143,rank:7,avatar:"avatar_3",prize:245},{id:"something8",score:143,rank:8,avatar:"avatar_4",prize:245},{id:"something9",score:140,rank:9,avatar:"avatar_3",prize:210}];

const out = {};

// Iterate over the data
for (const obj of data) {

  // Destructure the score an prize from each object
  const { score, prize } = obj;

  // Initialise the key/value of an `out` property
  // with an object with default values
  out[score] ??= { players: 0, prizes: 0 };

  // Increase the players count
  ++out[score].players;

  // Add the prize of the current object to
  // the `prizes` value
  out[score].prizes += obj.prize;

  // Calculate the current score
  out[score].total = out[score].prizes / out[score].players;
}

// Return a new array of objects updating each
// score with the `total` value from the hash object
const result = data.map(obj => {
  return { ...obj, prize: out[obj.score].total };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
const computeAveragePrizes = (arr) => {
  const grouped = arr.reduce((acc , cur) => {
        const existing = acc[cur.score];
        if (existing) {
          return {
            ...acc ,
            [cur.score]: {
              total: existing.total + cur.prize ,
              count: existing.count + 1
            }
          }
        }

        return {
          ...acc ,
          [cur.score]: {
            total: cur.prize ,
            count: 1
          }
        }
      } , {}
  );

  return arr.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    prize: grouped[item.score].total / grouped[item.score].count
  }))
}
```